# How to determine the index during page change using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, indexing

I have total of 13 records and size 3 per page.

records `record` are in array of object and displayed it in card which works.

Page 1 records will have response  3 records,

Page 2 records will have response another 3 records

...Page N

For each card, i display the record index

on page, card will be like

```
page 1;
card1->
index 1 // written code as ++i

card2->
index 2

card3-> 
index 3


Expected behaviour for page 2
page 2;
card1-> 
index 4 // should continue 

card2-> 
index 5

card3-> 
index 6
```

Currently for the page2 am returning index as

```
wrong behaviour
page 2;
card1-> 
index 1 {++i} does not work for 2 second page still treated as index from 0
 
card2-> 
index 2

card3-> 
index 3
```

Tried

```
// for page 1, i get as
var records = [
  {id: 21, color: "red"},
  {id: 32, color: "blue"},
  {id: 52, color: "green"}
]

// for page 2, i get as

var records = [
  {id: 21, color: "brown"},
  {id: 42, color: "indigo"},
  {id: 22, color: "yellow"}
]

// also i retreive total records as well
[
  {id: 21, color: "red"},
  {id: 32, color: "blue"},
  {id: 52, color: "green"},
  {id: 21, color: "brown"},
  {id: 42, color: "indigo"},
  {id: 22, color: "yellow"}
]

displaying as


{records.map((e, i)=> 
   <div>Card {++i}</div>
  <div>Index {++i}</div> // this value on page2 should not repeat same index

)}
```

Comment: Please include the code you have that is relevant for this question.

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried to get this result ?

Comment: @HediZitouni, i have updated the question that tried

Comment: @trincot updated the question, include what i tried

Comment: Your code is node usable as it is. 
But what I understood, is that index should equals: "3*pageIndex+i+1" instead of "++i".
I can't tell you how to get pageIndex with the code you provided.

Also, avoid ++i and prefer i+1 in this case. You can have undesirable side effects

Comment: for each card, on page 2, i should not display as 1, 2, 3 again instead i need to display as 4, 5,6 and  page 3 should have 7,8,9 and so on..not sure how to achieve this

Comment: As I said. in fact 4 | 5 | 6 is in reality  3*1 +0 + 1 | 3*1 + 1 + 1 | 3*1 + 2 + 1. So your mathemaical formula is 3 * pageIndex + i + 1. WIth pageIndex the number of your page, i the index of your card (0, 1 or 2)

Comment: @HediZitouni thanks the what about page 1, it  will change to 4, 5,6 if i use ur method,  so what i tried is pageIndex === 1 ? (i + 1) : (size * (pageIndex - 1)) + (i + 1) is the way correct

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are really just trying to paginate through an array. So for that you can use **array.slice** to get the part of the array that you want. My answer, you just pass the array of results, the number to show per page and the current page.

```js
const results = [
  {id: 21, color: "red"},
  {id: 32, color: "blue"},
  {id: 52, color: "green"},
  {id: 21, color: "brown"},
  {id: 42, color: "indigo"},
  {id: 22, color: "yellow"}
];

const getResults = (arry, perPage, page) => {
  const start = page * perPage - perPage;
  const end = start + perPage;
  return arry.slice(start, end);
};

console.log(getResults(results, 3, 1))
console.log(getResults(results, 3, 2))
```